# How to typecast "Integer" data to "int" datatype in Java?

Tags: java

```
Integer key = new Integer(2);
int mod = 13;
int index = key%13;

"Error:java: bad operand types for binary operator '%' first type:  Integer  second type: int"
```

I want to convert the key%13 to a int type value and access it!

Comment: That should work for all versions of Java from Java 5 onwards.  Check that your IDE doesn't have the Java compliance level set to a really old version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not required to use a specific compiler, change your compiler to 1.5 or above since AutoBoxing was a new feature introduced in Java SE 5.

> **Autoboxing** is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing. (source: [Oracle, The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html))

**Possible solutions will be:**

1. Change the version of your Java compiler in your IDE.
2. Use the option -source 1.5 (or above) in your javac command when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

These are the best ways to convert an `Integer` to an `int`.

In Java 5 and later, just use auto-unboxing; e.g.

```
  Integer i = new Integer(5);  // (not the best way to create an Integer ...)
  int ii = i;    // the value is automatically unboxed.
```

Prior to Java 5, use `Integer::intValue` to manually unbox the value; e.g.

```
  Integer i = new Integer(5);
  int ii = i.intValue();
```

(The suggestion of using `toString` and `parseInt` is very inefficient.)

---

Your example code *should* compile.  If it doesn't then it means one of two possible things:

1. Your Java compiler source code compliance level is set to Java 1.4.x or earlier.  This may be due to an explicit `-source` option in your build script, a default in the build tool you are using, or a setting in your IDE.  Either way, you should fix it.
2. The `Integer` type that you are using is not `java.lang.Integer`.  In other words, you have declared your own `Integer` class or imported one from some (misguided) 3rd-party library.